# Moved to HTTPS. Do I need to do anything on the Google Analytics side?

Tags: google-analytics, https

Recently I changed my site to support HTTPS by default, and have setup 301 redirects from HTTP version.

I want to make sure nothing breaks on the GA side. Is there anything I should do on GA other than changing the site URL to HTTPS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your analytics itself is not affected by HTTPS. Your metrics will continue to load just fine.

You must be paying attention with your site speed that one will affected by HTTPS.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend changing the Website URL to 'HTTPS' as shown in the screenshot from "View Settings" and "Property Settings". Also add the HTTPS version of the URL in the Webmaster tools as well. 
[image: Google Analytics HTTPS Setup]

Comment: I didn't even know that setting was there in GA.   Good find.